# Flask многопоточность

Tags: python, многопоточность, flask

Привет всем. Есть web-приложение на flask(Python 3). На него посылаются данные post запросом(вк api), приложение должно обработать их. Результат(то, что посылается в ответ на запрос, return 'ok',200) должен быть всегда одинаковым. Задача такая:
Принять запрос, отправить его "дальше по коду"
Параллельно с этим сделать return или отправить это сообщение('ok') и статус(200) клиенту(вк), если этого не сделать, он начнёт флудить запросами, что поведёт за собой ошибки. Пока есть идея на счёт многопоточности:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def mpage():
    decoded = request.get_json()
    text = obj["body"]
    inp = list(text.split(sep=' '))
    thread = Thread(target=seps, args=inp)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    return 'ok',200
def task(inp):
    #Задача
```

Но при запуске появляется ошибка:

```
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: task() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Когда ошибка начала появляться, я понял, что что-то не так. 
В общем, прошу помочь с проблемой(Не решить ошибку, хотя если то единственное правильное решение задачи, то тоже подойдёт)

Comment: По-хорошему такие вещи должны делаться примерно так: 1) Flask запускается с помощью стороннего многопоточного сервера (uwsgi или gunicorn); 2) После получения запроса он отправляется в очередь задач, отдельную от фласка (на базе RabbitMQ, например), а вконтакту фласк возвращает 200 ok и больше ничего не делает; 3) Совершенно отдельный процесс, не связанный никак с фласком и вебом, забирает его из этой очереди и выполняет нужные вам действия. А самостоятельно потоки в веб-сервере лучше не запускать, в общем случае так не принято

Comment: Старайте ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос. Сперва `TypeError` разрешите, затем дальше проблемы решайте, к примеру `thread.join()` блокирует текущий поток. Создавать на каждый запрос, новый поток скорее всего не нужно. Можно попробовать пул потоков использовать `pool.submit(func, *args)`, где pool создаётся только единожды при старте сервиса `pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)` (если с помощью gunicorn запускаете, то в `on_starting` можете пул создать) . Используйте самое простое решение, которое работает. В более общем случае, посмотрите [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените:

```
 thread = Thread(target=seps, args=inp)
```

на:

```
 thread = Thread(target=seps, args=(inp,))
```

Comment: А как в целом? Способ будет нормально работать?

Comment: ИМХО, лучше делать так, как предложил @andreymal