# Flask. Безопасна ли многопоточность при длительном расчете?

Tags: python, многопоточность, flask

Есть задача - скажем загрузить три разных файла, когда файлы загружены, надо запустить их обработку (секунд 20). Вот такой шаблон вроде работает, но есть сомнения в безопасности такого подхода из-за коммментариев в смежном [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634628/flask-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)  .

```
@amz.route('/<code>/<amz_id>/calculate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def calculate(code, amz_id):
    work_dir=current_upload_path(code, amz_id)
    files_in_dir = [ el.name for el in work_dir.iterdir()]
    ...
    import time
    import threading

    def super_calc():
        time.sleep(20)

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=super_calc)  
    t1.start()

    return render_template('calculate.html', 
                        code=code, amz_id=amz_id, 
                        test_list=files_in_dir)
```

Это всего лишь шаблон. интересует сам механизм отсутствия "зависания" на 20 секунд.  Если интересено - после расчета отправляется итоговый файл на один из адресов клиента.  То есть окончательный результат отложенный...
То есть меня интересует вопрос - не возникнет ли каких сбоев, если во время обработки кто то запустит новый поток, введя три файла другого клиента?
.
Дополню вопрос проьбой привести пример, как это правильно делать. Неужели действительно здесь нужны  [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) или [RQ (Redis Queue)](http://python-rq.org/) ?
.................................................................
Конкретизирую вопрос. Есть ли какой то конструктивный способ определить, когда достаточно использования threading, а когда нужно обращаться к Celery?

Comment: Короткий ответ: вообще нет. Для таких штук есть брокеры сообщений. Например celery, весьма популярный.

Comment: @mrEvgenX  Тут https://khashtamov.com/ru/celery-best-practices/   написано что селери лучше не использовать для длинных задач.... ЦИТирую.
Long-running tasks
Старайтесь не использовать Celery для выполнения долгих задач. На этот аргумент есть ряд причин:
    Процессы, живущие долго, потребляют память, но не освобождают её. Даже с учётом работы сборщика мусора. Такой механизм необходим, чтобы избежать фрагментации оперативной памяти.
    Celery заточен на выполнение большого количества задач, требующих мало времени на их исполнение. Когда задачи выполняются долго, образуются очереди

Comment: Я лишь привел пример, может кто-то лучше подойдет. В приведенной статье ни слова про критерии, как относить те или иные задачи к long-running. По мне - задача обучить нейросетку для продакшена - long-running иногда даже с приставкой very. А 20 секунд - не так уж и long-running. Но если они с огромной частотой сыпятся... Кажется, это уже совсем другой вопрос. Как считаете?

Comment: https://medium.com/@prabhakarparam/using-celery-to-perform-long-running-tasks-in-a-web-application-31da725833cc здесь к long-running относят любые задачи, которые не позволяют интерактивно взаимодействовать с системой, т.е. без почти мгновенного отклика.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая проблема решения с потоками в том, что никак не ограничивается количество запущенных потоков и ресурсов сервера под это выделенных. Решения типа celery позволяют это контролировать.

Следующая проблема с потоками в том, что если, например, после начала выполнения такого фонового потока на сервере произойдет сбой (приложение рухнет, сервер перезагрузится, виртуалку AWS прикончит или вообще весь сервер сгорит), то информация о том, что есть такая задача и ее нужно выполнить пропадет полностью.

Можно, конечно, придумывать и пытаться как-то сохранять факт, что нужно сделать такую задачу, потом при старте веб приложения, смотреть, нет ли там невыполненных задач. Но это очень нетривиально, там есть куча нюансов. И celery как раз - это то, что нужно для такой задачи.

В celery очень просто сконфигурировать задачу, чтобы при сбое, она автоматически запускалась заново. Нужно, конечно, саму задачу тоже реализовывать с учетом того, что, возможно, это повторный запуск.

Что касается долгих задач, то тут нет ничего таинственного, и все решаемо планированием и распределением ресурсов. Потенциальная проблема в том, что если у вас есть задачи критичные по времени (типичный пример, пользователь нажимает кнопку, часть обработки происходит в фоне с использованием celery, и результат действия отображается пользователю, но не в рамках синхронного http запроса, а например push через websocket), то наличие задач, которые выполняются скажем 20 секунд, могут сильно повредить, задержки будут сильно влиять на user experience.

Это обычное дело и решение тоже простое, создаются разные очереди для разных задач. У каждой очереди свой выделенный набор рабочих процессов. Так "длинные" задачи помещаются в одну очередь, а "быстрые" в другую и они друг друга не блокируют. Несложно в таком случае вообще рабочие процессы celery перенести на отдельные сервера.

Теперь об утечках памяти в celery. Действительно, в старых версиях celery есть эта проблема (не знаю как в новых, может исправили, у нас на проде довольно старая версия и я только о ней могу говорить). Не знаю связана ли проблема с длительностью задач - не исследовал, но, по ощущениям - нет. Но самое главное, что это не так важно, так как легко решается. У celery есть опция конфигурации рабочего процесса - перегружать рабочий процесс после того, как он выполнит определенное количество задач. У нас на проде это делается после 1000 задач. Это полностью решает проблему с утечками памяти, без необходимости приложению что-либо знать об этой проблеме.