# Многопоточность python сервера и while

Tags: python, многопоточность, flask

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как возможно организовать работу сервера и одновременную проверку условия в цикле while? Ожидается Py сервер на flask, принимающий JSON из другого py скрипта, и проверяющий его на равенство предыдущему. Затем через сокеты передающий этот JSON в javascript для визуализации. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?

```
while (333): 
    tempJSON=subprocess.check_output(['/var/www/html/socket/commLobby.py'],
    universal_newlines=True)
    if (tempJSON != jsonIn):
        jsonIn=tempJSON
        print("there  ", jsonIn)

"""""""""""""""""" 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8001)), app)
```

Comment: Что касается именно многопоточности, то смотрите [коментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634628/flask-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c?rq=1#comment895368_634628)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите остаться в одном процессе, можно попробовать поработать с модулем `Threads`, но из-за блокировки интерпретатора, скорее всего будут проблемы (к примеру цикл будет периодически стоять или вообще не сможет работать).
Остается только сделать суб-процесс модулем `multiprocessing` (запускать второй процесс одновременно с процессом сервера) и в нем запускать цикл while.

Comment: Благодарю, попробую сделать так, как Вы сказали